# Why google authentication works well in development & staging modes but does not work in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, single-sign-on, omniauth-google-oauth2

I've got a problem with configuring google authentication in my ruby on rails application using `devise` and `omniauth-google-oauth2`.

After carefully following instructions from omniauth-google-oauth2 github readme I've added Authorized redirect URIs to settings list:

`https://<production_domain>/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`
`https://<staging_subdomain>/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`
`http://localhost:3000/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`

The issue is that authorization works well in **development** and **staging** environments, but does not work in **production** mode.

Trying to authenticate in production I'm getting:

`Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch`

Request details
`redirect_uri=https://<production_domain>/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`

it seems very strange to me cause mentioned callback is present in my Authorized redirect URIs to settings list.

Help me please to set up authentication in production evironment.
Fell free to ask me about any additional information.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious have you verified that the redirect URL you have provided in the provider settings matches the actual url?

Comment: I've provided callback URI, which is `https://<production_domain>/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`, which is exactly the same as `redirect_uri` asked by google at the error details.
By the way, are callback uri redirect uri same things?